# Grails : Add values to many to many relationships and store them in database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

I have two classes Vehicule and Garage.

Vehicule is a type of vehicule (Truck, Car, Bus...)

A garage could have many type of vehicule.

And a type of vehicule could be associated to many garages.

So I can retrieve all garages which have a vehicule type, and all vehicule type from a Garage.

```
Class Vehicule extends Content implements Serializable {
    String type // PEUGEOT / BMW ...

    static hasMany = [garages: Garage]
}

Class Garage extends Content implements Serializable {
     static hasMany = [
         vehicules: Vehicule,
         users: User
     ]
}
```

In database, I have the association table well created.

In Bootstrap.groovy, I pre-populate my database.

```
def user1 = new User(...).save()
def garage1 = new Garage(...).save()
def garage2 = new Garage(...).save()
def garage3 = new Garage(...).save()

def vehicule1 = new Vehicule(...).save()
def vehicule2 = new Vehicule(...).save()
def vehicule3 = new Vehicule(...).save()
```

**At this stage, everything works fine !**

Indeed, I can see in my MySQL database all the instances of "Vehicule", "Garage" and "User".

**------------------------HERE THE ISSUE------------------------**

Still in **Bootstrap.groovy**, I tried to create relationships between my instances.

```
garage1.addToVehicules(vehicule1)
garage1.addToVehicules(vehicule2)
garage2.addToVehicules(vehicule1)
garage3.addToVehicules(vehicule1)
garage1.addToUsers(user1)

vehicule1.addToGarages(garage1)
vehicule1.addToGarages(garage2)
vehicule1.addToGarages(garage3)
...
```

Then, I save it and manage to be aware of any errors.

```
if (!garage1.save()) {
     log.error garage1.errors.allErrors.join(' \n')
}

if (!garage2.save()) {
     log.error garage2.errors.allErrors.join(' \n')
}
...
```

At compiling and launching, no errors, no stacktrace.

But when I am visiting my MySQL database, **none** of the mapping tables are filled. (*vehicule_garages* is empty, *garage_vehicules* is empty and *garage_users* is empty)

**------------------------END OF THE ISSUE------------------------**

What am I missing ?

No errors in the code, instances of objects saved, but no relationship.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Vehicule and Garage are saved in database?

Answer (score 0):

In many to many you can use an intermediate class like GarageVehicule

```
class GarageVehicule {

  Vehicule vehicule
  Garage garage

  static belongsTo = [
    vehicule: Vehicule,
    garage: Garage
  ]

}
```

Garage:

```
class Garage {

  static hasMany = [
    garageVehicules: GarageVehicule
  ]

}
```

Vehicule:

```
class Vehicule {

  String type

  static hasMany = [
    garageVehicules: GarageVehicule
  ]

}
```

In Boostrap:

```
def garage1 = new Garage().save(failOnError: true)
def vehicule1 = new Vehicule(type: 'BMW').save(failOnError: true)

new GarageVehicule(vehicule: vehicule1, garage: garage1).save(failOnError: true) // with failOnError you will see the errors if a domain has erros and you try to save it.
```

Data is saved in GarageVehicule.

[image]